# Ruby Regex repeating patterns

Tags: ruby, regex, repeat

I need to extract the \d values before the characters enclosed in quotes, so the result for

```
teststring.scan(/regex/)
```

should be

```
=> [["4"], ["2"], ["1"]]
```

Teststring:

```
testtring = '4 x "UM 4 ENGLISH" 2 x "UM FRENCH" 1 x "SOME OTHER STRING WHICH COULD CONTAIN 2 x"'
```

My first approach was something like this, in different variations:

```
(\d) x ".+" ?
((\d) x ".+" ?)+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude qoutes inside the quoted parts:

```
teststring.scan(/(\d) x "[^"]+"/)
```

Alternatively, use non-greedy match:

```
teststring.scan(/(\d) x ".+?"/)
```

Also, consider using a quantifier for the digits to support more than one digit.

```
teststring.scan(/(\d+) x "[^"]+"/)
```

Comment: I think that should be `teststring.scan(/(?:(\d) x "[^"]*")+/)` The regex group modifier `?=` is a look-ahead - so it does not consume characters matched. It probably explains why you got away with the greedy match `.+`, in fact your advice to use `[^"]` is sound.

Comment: I think Trygve identified the correct approach, but got the syntax a little wrong. This answer can be fixed. BTW, the `+` at the end is also not necessary, only one outer group is ever matched at a time

Comment: @Neil Yup, thanks for your corrections. I did indeed mix up lookahead and noncapturing syntax. Answer edited.